# Counting data points within limits, and applying buffer to isolated points [data analysis]

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, signal-processing

I am stuck trying to solve this problem:

I have a set of data points, that correspond to a set of time values. i.e. `values =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,4] times = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]...` and so on, it's a sample rate of 10hz.

I need to find the time spent between two limits. so for example if my limits are 3 and 5 inclusive then 3,4,5,4 are in my limits.

if I calculate the time as number of (`points -1) /sample rate`, or the start time and end time of the grouping, I will miss out the isolated data point (the second 4)

I have proposed to use an imaginary buffer of half the sample rate either side to model the isolated events.

but I am having trouble implementing this in code (python)
I need a way of iterating through the points, counting the number of points, with a pairing to be able to perform (number of points-1)/ sample rate. and also how to pick up the singular points and apply the buffer value to the number of points.

I can't seem to find the right combination of `if` and `while` statements to do this.

[image]

Comment: In order to understand it right: `times` items are always increasing by the sample rate? `time[n] == (n+1)/sample_rate`?

Comment: @KlausD. no times items are just a set of linear time according to a sample rate, so for each event it takes 0.1 seconds , or 10hz.
so for 10 values, the times values would be 0 to 0.9 or 0.1 ti 10.0 it doesn't really matter, the crux of the problem is counting groups of continuous "in limit" sets, and counting isolated sets

Comment: And what is the difference except that my version is more technical?

Comment: So if the limits are `lo_limit` and `hi_limit` you just want to know how many elements `x` of `values` are in the range  `lo_limit <= x <= hi_limit`. Is that correct?

Comment: there's no difference, apologies, do you have any ideas how to solve the issue, one suggestion was to group consecutive points with a new piece of data (group number) , i'd love your insight, thanks.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes that's correct, however when we convert the number of points to time using the sample rate, we miss out the single elements/ it's not accurate, my suggestion is to use a buffer of half the sample rate for every single event, which should be a reasonable approximation for how much time the event is between limits.

so I need a way of finding the number of points that are consecutively in the limits.

and the number of points that are only within the limit for one point, in which case we have to assume the time is half the sample rate

Comment: Are the contents of `values` static or is it being continuously updated by the sampling process?

Comment: @PM2Ring static. this is a post-capture data analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that does what you want. Runs of multiple data points that are within the specified limits are given a time value equal to the number of data points times the sampling period (i.e. the reciprocal of the sampling frequency), isolated single points are given a value of half the sampling period.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Estimate time of data points falling within specified limits 
    From http://stackoverflow.com/q/29430625/4014959
    Written 2015.04.03 by PM 2Ring,
    with help from Antti Haapala and Martijn Pieters 
'''

from itertools import groupby

def estimate_time(values, lo_lim, hi_lim, sample_rate):
    #Find values that are in range
    in_range = [lo_lim <= v <= hi_lim for v in values]

    #Find runs of in-range values
    runs = [sum(1 for _ in group) for v, group in groupby(in_range) if v]

    #Estimate total time spent in-range
    total_time = sum(v if v > 1 else 0.5 for v in runs)
    return total_time / sample_rate


values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4]
sample_rate = 10.0  # in Hz

lo_lim = 3
hi_lim = 5

print estimate_time(values, lo_lim, hi_lim, sample_rate)
```

**output**

```
0.35
```

To check that this code really does what you want you can put some print statements into `estimate_time()` to show the contents of `in_range` and `runs`.

---

One thing you can do to reduce memory requirements is to convert the list comprehensions into generator expressions. List comprehensions have to create a whole new list in memory (which is deleted once it goes out of scope); a generator expression is a little slower, but it doesn't need to build a list - results are generated as they're needed. The syntax is very similar - just replace the square brackets of the list comp with round brackets to turn it into a gen exp.

So change

`in_range = [lo_lim <= v <= hi_lim for v in values]`
to
`in_range = (lo_lim <= v <= hi_lim for v in values)`

and

`runs = [sum(1 for _ in group) for v, group in groupby(in_range) if v]`
to
`runs = (sum(1 for _ in group) for v, group in groupby(in_range) if v)`

Comment: this works great for small ranges, I am in the process of trying to apply it to my data point sets >150000 points.

Comment: Thank's for your solution, do you have any resources for learning how to solve problems similar, I tend to just have lot's of while and if statements,  "for x in list" seems powerful.

Comment: Also, you can convert `in_range` and `runs` into generator expressions instead of list comprehensions. I'll show you what I mean in my answer.

Comment: @JoshuaJones: One way of learning good techniques is to study code written by good programmers. There are plenty of examples of great code here on Stackoverflow, and although sometimes people post code that just answers the problem at hand and don't necessarily follow best practice, a lot of people do submit professional quality code, especially many high-rep users like Martijn and Antti.

Comment: Of course, some of the more advanced techniques may be hard to understand, especially if you're still learning the basics of Python, but many of the high-rep users try to write code that's appropriate to the level of the person asking the question without using too many fancy tricks.

Comment: Thank You! It's very helpful to get feedback, I'll check out some of the higher rep users, one thing I am yet to use is the python functions that start with things like __init__ or __self__   ... no idea what they are for.

Comment: @JoshuaJones: `__init__` and `self` are used in [classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html). Classes can take a little while to get your head around, but they're definitely worth learning about.

Comment: I don't suppose there's anyone still watching this question who might help producing the same logic for 2 pairs of upper and lower limits, i.e. time is only registered if two data series values are within their respective limits?

Comment: @JoshuaJones: Please ask a new question, with a link back to this one. Explain what you're trying to do as clearly as possible, with sample input data and expected output. It would also be good if you could post your own attempt at some code for this new problem.

Comment: Sure, thanks for keeping up with the question, I've implemented it successfully for our single parameter case, I'll post a new question soon. I have two more use cases: compound time at level and multiple single use cases in a row which I think I can do but might be interesting to someone anyway. Is linking back a stack exchange feature or is it a simple hyperlink to the old question ?

Comment: @JoshuaJones: There's a short-ish link available for every question (and every answer). Click your mouse on the word `share` at the far left of the line just under the row of tags (eg [tag:python] [tag:if-statement] etc). The short link for your question is http://stackoverflow.com/q/29430625/4014959

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603334/calculating-time-within-limits-for-multiple-data-sets

Added a new, related question for those interested.

Comment: @JoshuaJones: Ok. I'll check it out when I'm awake. :)