# python generator expressions for two data sets

Tags: python, list, signal-processing, generator

```
#Find values that are in range
in_range = [lo_lim <= v <= hi_lim for v in values]
#Find runs of in-range values
runs = [sum(1 for _ in group) for v, group in groupby(in_range) if v]

#Estimate total time spent in-range
total_time = sum(v if v > 1 else (Buffer_Value*sample_rate) for v in runs)
```

I am trying to augment this code to take two sets of values, and 2 pairs of hi/lo limits,
to calculate the total time spent within these limits, the combined limits when the case 'in limit' is true for the same point, i.e.

if there are 100 data points (both data sets are the same length, check each point,

```
if values_1[45] and values_2[45] are in their respective limits
```

then count as in range.
Essentially turning this if into a generator expression:

```
if lo_lim_1<=Data_Points_1[i]<=hi_lim_1 and lo_lim_2<=Data_Points_2[i]<=hi_lim_2:
```

count the runs, if the run length is one data point then apply a buffer otherwise apply the sample rate conversion.

Comment: Isn't `sum(1 for _ in group)` just `len(group)`?

Comment: @user1016274 replacing (1) for (2) breaks my code, so no.

Comment: @user1016274 not if `group` is an iterator, as it is with `groupby`.  Iterators don't have lengths.

Comment: @TheBlackCat thank you for expanding and giving an explanation, I did not know why :)

Comment: Now that you have an answer, you may wish to delete [Calculating time within limits for multiple data sets](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29603334/4014959), since it's essentially a duplicate of this question. PS: You now have enough rep to vote! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, this should work.  The basic idea is you `zip` up the two sequences into pairs of corresponding values, then use an `and` operation to find cases where they are both within their corresponding range:

```
#Find values that are in range
in_range = [lo_lim1 <= v1 <= hi_lim1 and lo_lim2 <= v2 <= hi_lim2 for v1, v2 in zip(values1, values2)]

# code is unchanged from here
#Find runs of in-range values
runs = [sum(1 for _ in group) for v, group in groupby(in_range) if v]  # this is the same as yours

#Estimate total time spent in-range
total_time = sum(v if v > 1 else (Buffer_Value*sample_rate) for v in runs)
```

In your case, if you are using python 2.x, you can use `itertools.izip` instead of `zip` to save some memory, and for python 2.x and 3.x you can use a generator expression to save some more:

```
#Find values that are in range
in_range = (lo_lim1 <= v1 <= hi_lim1 and lo_lim2 <= v2 <= hi_lim2 for v1, v2 in zip(values1, values2))

#Find runs of in-range values
runs = (sum(1 for _ in group) for v, group in groupby(in_range) if v)  # this is the same as yours

#Estimate total time spent in-range
defval = Buffer_Value*sample_rate
total_time = sum(v if v > 1 else defval for v in runs)
```

Comment: works great, thank you, can you point me towards some good tutorials on these types of problems?

Comment: No, sorry.  It is just a matter of getting a handle on list comprehensions, the builtin functions, and itertools.

Comment: Nice work, TheBlackCat. FWIW, here's [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29432398/4014959) to Joshua's original question.